# Scrape Data through RVest

Tags: r, rvest

I am looking to get the article names by category from https://www.inquirer.net/article-index?d=2020-6-13

I've attempted to read the article names by doing:

```
library('rvest')

year <- 2020
month <- 06
day <- 13
url <- paste('http://www.inquirer.net/article-index?d=', year, '-', month, '-',day, sep = "")

 pg <- read_html(url)

 test<-pg %>%
  html_nodes("#index-wrap") %>%
  html_text()
```

This returns only 1 string of all articles names and it's very messy.

I ultimately would like to have a dataframe that looks like below:

```
       Date     Category      Article Name
 2020-06-13         News      ‘We can never let our guard down’ vs terrorism – Cayetano
 2020-06-13         News      PNP spox says mañanita remark did not intend to put Sinas in bad light
 2020-06-13         News      After stranded mom’s death, Pasay LGU helps over 400 stranded individuals
 2020-06-13        World      4 dead after tanker truck explodes on highway in China
 etc.
 etc.
 etc.
 etc.
 2020-06-13    Lifestyle     Book: Melania Trump delayed 2017 move to DC to get new prenup
```

Does anyone know what I may be missing? Very new to this, thanks!

Comment: Hi nak. Have you tried `read_html(url)` instead of just `url`?

Comment: Yup I tried that and it only returns 1 result in a long string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is maybe the closest you can get:

```r
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
library(tibble)

year  <- 2020
month <- 06
day   <- 13
url   <- paste0('http://www.inquirer.net/article-index?d=', year, '-', month, '-', day)

div       <- read_html(url) %>% html_node(xpath = '//*[@id ="index-wrap"]')
links     <- html_nodes(div, xpath = '//a[@rel = "bookmark"]') 
post_date <- html_nodes(div, xpath = '//span[@class = "index-postdate"]') %>% 
             html_text()

test <- tibble(date = post_date,
               text = html_text(links),
               link = html_attr(links, "href"))

test
#> # A tibble: 261 x 3
#>    date     text                              link                              
#>    <chr>    <chr>                             <chr>                             
#>  1 1 day a~ ‘We can never let our guard down~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#>  2 1 day a~ PNP spox says mañanita remark di~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#>  3 1 day a~ After stranded mom’s death, Pasa~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#>  4 1 day a~ Putting up lining for bike lanes~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#>  5 1 day a~ PH Army provides accommodation f~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#>  6 1 day a~ DA: Local poultry production suf~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#>  7 1 day a~ IATF assessing proposed design t~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#>  8 1 day a~ PCSO lost ‘most likely’ P13B dur~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#>  9 2 days ~ DOH: No IATF recommendations yet~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#> 10 2 days ~ PH coronavirus cases exceed 25,0~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#> # ... with 251 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Just curious, I'm trying to learn what you did. I think I understand `xpath = //*[@id ="index-wrap"]` How did you know that was the location? I am trying to duplicate it using SelectorGadget. Same goes for the bookmark portion

Comment: because essentially what I am trying to do is have 1 more column with the clean article text. and attempted this: article_data<-data.frame(test)
article_url<- read_html(article_data[2, 3])
article<-article_url %>%
  html_nodes("#art_body_wrap") %>%
  html_text()

Comment: I can post the above as a new question as well

Comment: using this as a tutorial at the moment which may help http://flukeout.github.io/

Comment: @nak5120 it's probably better as a new question, otherwise we might end up in comment ping-pong for a long time.

Comment: Sounds good, new question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62379075/rvest-reading-separated-article-data

Answer (score 2):

you fogot read_html() then use that in the dplyr statment

```
library('rvest')

year <- 2020
month <- 06
day <- 13
url <- paste('http://www.inquirer.net/article-index?d=', year, '-', month, '-',day, sep = "")

#added page
page <- read_html(url)

test <- page %>%
  #changed xpath
  html_node(xpath = '//*[@id ="index-wrap"]') %>%
  html_text()

test
```

update, i suck at dplyr but this is what i have before i go to bed

```
library('rvest')

year <- 2020
month <- 06
day <- 13
url <- paste('http://www.inquirer.net/article-index?d=', year, '-', month, '-',day, sep = "")

#addad page
page <- read_html(url)

titles <- page %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id ="index-wrap"]/h4') %>%
  html_text()

sections <- page %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id ="index-wrap"]/ul')


stories <- sections %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//li/a') %>%
  html_text()

stories
```

Comment: thanks, I think I can make this work. Looks like everything is in 1 string now and will just need to parse out the category from the \r\n\t\t\t\t\tNEWS\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t string. Is there a better way to make this cleaner?