# Rvest reading separated article data

Tags: r, rvest

I am looking to scrape article data from inquirer.net.

This is a follow-up question to [Scrape Data through RVest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62377801/scrape-data-through-rvest)

Here is the code that works based on the answer:

```
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
library(tibble)

year  <- 2020
month <- 06
day   <- 13
url   <- paste0('http://www.inquirer.net/article-index?d=', year, '-', month, '-', day)

div       <- read_html(url) %>% html_node(xpath = '//*[@id ="index-wrap"]')
links     <- html_nodes(div, xpath = '//a[@rel = "bookmark"]') 
post_date <- html_nodes(div, xpath = '//span[@class = "index-postdate"]') %>% 
             html_text()

test <- tibble(date = post_date,
               text = html_text(links),
               link = html_attr(links, "href"))

test
#> # A tibble: 261 x 3
#>    date     text                              link                              
#>    <chr>    <chr>                             <chr>                             
#>  1 1 day a~ ‘We can never let our guard down~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#>  2 1 day a~ PNP spox says mañanita remark di~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#>  3 1 day a~ After stranded mom’s death, Pasa~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#>  4 1 day a~ Putting up lining for bike lanes~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#>  5 1 day a~ PH Army provides accommodation f~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#>  6 1 day a~ DA: Local poultry production suf~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#>  7 1 day a~ IATF assessing proposed design t~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#>  8 1 day a~ PCSO lost ‘most likely’ P13B dur~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#>  9 2 days ~ DOH: No IATF recommendations yet~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#> 10 2 days ~ PH coronavirus cases exceed 25,0~ https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/129~
#> # ... with 251 more rows
```

I now want to add a new column to this output which has the full article for each row. Before doing the for-loop, I was investigating the html code for the first article: https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/1291178/pnp-spox-says-he-did-not-intend-to-put-sinas-in-bad-light

Digging into the html code, I'm noticing it is not that clean. From my findings so far, the main article data falls under `#article_content , p`. So my output right now is multiple rows separated and there is a lot of non-article data appearing. here is what I have currently:

```
article_data<-data.frame(test)
article_url<- read_html(article_data[2, 3])
article<-article_url %>%
   html_nodes("#article_content , p") %>%
   html_text()
View(article)
```

[image]

I'm ok with this being multiple rows because I can just union the final result. But since there are other non-article items then it will mess up what I am trying to do (sentiment analysis).

Can someone please assist on how to clean this data so that the full article is next to each article link?

I could simply just union the results excluding the first row and last 2 rows but looking for a cleaner way because I want to do this for all article data and not just this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a short look in the structure of the article page, I suggest using the css selector: `".article_align div p"`.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://newsinfo.inquirer.net/1291178/pnp-spox-says-he-did-not-intend-to-put-sinas-in-bad-light"

read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes(".article_align div p") %>% 
  html_text()
```